# Users have no option to review my app in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I published an android game a week ago, and it got published yesterday.  I made an update to it today.  I have started advertising and asking friends to play and review it but no one can review my game.  There is no button for them to review on mobile and there is no review section at all on pc.  Does anyone know why this might be?  The game has been on the store for at least a day.

Comment: There might be various delays due to COVID-19. And Google was never very reliable to start with. Wait at least a month and then see. I also think now was a bad time for advertising your app due to indexing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to wait.  For some reason apps in google play can take some time before user reviews are allowed.  It took a few days before reviews were allowed on the app.